# Using dynamic where clause hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to build a query where some of the fields are being sent from the client side based on user selection.
I am planing to create a dynamic query based on the selection by user.Though i can do it simply with some java code and den let hibernate to fire that Query for me and return the result.

My question is, can i do same using build in hibernate mechanism.
e.g i will get a map say

```
(cond1:a,cond2:b,cond3:c)
```

only difference is the number of values map can contain and based on that i want to create a query
like

```
select * from demo where cond1='a' and cond2='b' and cond3='c'; and may be 
select * from demo where cond1='a' and cond2='b'; when map has only 2 values
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem by using [criteria](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/).

```
CriteriaBuilder queryBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = queryBuilder.createQuery();
Root<Demo> demo = query.from(Demo.class);

Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
Map.Entry wherePair = (Map.Entry)it.next();  // This is retrieved for creating the where clause
query.where(wherePair.getKey() + "=" + wherePair.getValue());

while (it.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
   query.and(" " + pairs.getKey() + "=" + pairs.getValue());
}
```

I can't guarantee it will compile, but that'd be the idea.

Comment: How can we initialize EntityManager?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Criteria queries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querycriteria.html), they are especially designed for this scenario. Once you created a criteria query, you can iterate over your map and add appropriate restrictions to the query.