# When to use Criteria and when to use 'Where' clause queries in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

When to use Criteria and when to use 'Where' clause queries in hibernate ?

Comment: May be look this one. it will helps i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476658/using-dynamic-where-clause-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

For a static query, I find HQL queries much more readable (and concise) than criteria queries.

I see two reasons for criteria queries:

1. The query is not static, but dynamically created. Assume you have a search form with many search criteria, many of them being optional. You'll need to dynamically create a query based on the presence and value of the various search parameters. This is where criteria queries help you.
2. You have several complex static queries, all sharing common parts. In this case, rather than duplicating these common parts in every static query, it can be useful to use a criteria query, and factor the addition of the common parts in methods.